# How to get a reference on a sub array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm trying to get a reference on a sub array from a existing array.
I want to be able to update the original array when i'm doing a modification on the sub array.
Example :

```
byte[] array = {0 , 1, 2, 3, 4};
byte[] subarray = array.Skip(2).Take(3).ToArray();
subarray[0] = 8;
Console.WriteLine("array[2] = " + array[2]);
```

I want to see :

> array[2] = 8

but instead, i get :

> array[2] = 2

I read this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068984/getting-subarray-as-reference-in-c-sharp) but its not good enough because I dont want to give the option to modify array values that are not in the range, like this :

```
ArraySegment<byte> segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(array, 2, 3);
byte[] segmentByte = segment.ToArray();
```

I can modifiy all the original array through `segmentByte`. This is what i want to prevent.

Comment: How about using ArraySegment as specified as an answer in the link you provided?

Comment: @ArraySegment: "Multiple ArraySegment<T> instances can refer to the same original array and can overlap.", "changes made to the array returned by the Array property are made to the original array." > sounds like exactly what you want, what do you mean by "option to modify .... not in the range"?

Comment: When you do `ToArray()` it creates a complete new object which don't have any relation with the main array.

Comment: I added the explanation why i don't want to use ArraySegment

Comment: How up-to-date is your tech stack - C# 7.2 introduced `Span<T>`...

Comment: In your example `ToArray()` is actually a `Enumerable.ToArray<of TSource>()` extension method that creates new array filled with elements of an `ArraySegment<of T>`. Anyway, you can't use `ArraySegment<of T>` because it contains [`Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hetzw6es(v=vs.110).aspx) property that doesn't satisfy your requirement.

Comment: @JamesThorpe there is actually a [System.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory) NuGet package (currently only preview) with a slow version of `Span<of T>` that doesn't require language support. You can use it even in .NET Framework 4.5 applications. Although it satisfies OP's requirement and even slow version is very fast, it has limitations. For example, you can't store `Span<of T>` instances on the heap. See [Span](http://adamsitnik.com/Span/) article by Adam Sitnik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write simple `Array` and `ArraySegment<of T>` wrapper that provides set of required operations only:

```
struct StrictRangeArraySegment<T>
{
    ArraySegment<T> _segment;
    public StrictRangeArraySegment(T[] array) 
        : this(array, 0, array.Length)
    {
    }
    public StrictRangeArraySegment(T[] array, int offset, int count)
        : this(new ArraySegment<T>(array, offset, count))
    {
    }
    public StrictRangeArraySegment(ArraySegment<T> segment)
    {
        _segment = segment;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _segment.Count;
        }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= _segment.Count)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
            return _segment.Array[_segment.Offset + index];
        }
        set
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= _segment.Count)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
            _segment.Array[_segment.Offset + index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

For reference see [`ArraySegment<Of T>` source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/arraysegment.cs).

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at `ToList` method, you will see that it completely generate a new list which is not referred to the old one at all. So what you change only reflect to `subarray` only.

The only solution is to use that `ArraySegment` that you don't want to.

```
public List<TResult> ToList()
{
    var list = new List<TResult>();

    foreach (TSource item in _source)
    {
        list.Add(_selector(item));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: well they *could* put (references to) objects in the array, and modify a property in those objects. that would survive the reference copy. But it is much more expensive, storage- and performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

One option is creating a type to box your integers as a property of an object. Then updating the property will have the desired result:

```
public class Box<T>
{
    public T Value {get;set;}
    public Box<T>(T item) {Value = item;}
}

Box<byte>[] array = {new Box<byte>(0), new Box<byte>(1), new Box<byte>(2), new Box<byte>(3), new Box<byte>(4)};
Box<byte>[] subarray = array.Skip(2).Take(3).ToArray();
subarray[0].Value = 8;
Console.WriteLine("array[2] = " + array[2].Value);
//you'll see "8" instead of "2" now
```

You might also want to look at [`Span<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/docs/specs/span.md). It's not fully released yet, but it might make it possible to accomplish your goal here.